# how can i validate username password for mongodb authentication through pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, authentication

I am refering to the http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/authentication.html site for authentication mechanism examples. I have created a User administrator and using its credentials I created a user for my 'reporting' database. Now i need to access the same through pymongo using the username and password. I tried the following commands in python shell. Is this the right way as my authentication is failing.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost')

client.reporting.authenticate('reportsUser', '123456', mechanism='MONGODB-CR')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 746, in authenticate
    self.connection._cache_credentials(self.name, credentials)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 441, in _cache_credentials
    auth.authenticate(credentials, sock_info, self.__simple_command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 214, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials[1:], sock_info, cmd_func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 194, in _authenticate_mongo_cr
    cmd_func(sock_info, source, query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 607, in __simple_command
    helpers._check_command_response(response, None, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 147, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'reportsUser'), ('nonce', u'f8158a24f1c61650'), ('key', u'14cea216c54b93bae20acd2e076bb785')]) failed: auth failed
```

Comment: Did you add user ? did you start mongod in `--auth`  mode ?

Comment: Enabled auth=true in the mongod.conf and restarted mongod. what else is required?

Comment: add user to database

Comment: reportsUser is the user i created for reporting database. Do i need to add it to the admin database?

Comment: No, admin database user can access all database.Can you authenticate in mongo shell ?

Comment: It worked. I realized that my users were created with SCRAM-SHA-1 as default mechanism(using mongodb 3.0.1)) and I was providing MONGODB-CR. But when I provide SCRAM-SHA-1 it gives error. May because it requires python 2.8 and i am using 2.7. So i tried the following to change the default mechanism to MONGODB-CR and it worked: 
use admin;
db.system.version.save({ "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 3 })
then I created users again and to check I used the following :
use admin;
db.system.users.find({ "credentials.MONGODB-CR" : { $exists: true}}, { user: 1, db: 1}).
Thanks though :)

Comment: The user has to be created within the database. From what I can see, I assume you created the user in the admin database.

Answer (score 27):

As an FYI, you can use the URI string format as well.  The pseudocode looks like this:

*pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@server:port/')*

Here's a simple connection code block with auth:

```
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://root:pass@localhost:27017/')
db = conn['database']
coll = db['collection']
```

There are more options for the query string here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

Hope that helps = looks like you already have it though.  Happy coding!!

Comment: Is it possible to do it in 2 steps, like, 

`pymongo.MongoClient(server:port/', ssl = True, ssl_keyfile ="path to private key")`, then, 


`auth = client.admin.authenticate(mongo_username,mongo_password)`?

Is it possible to do this without passing the username, password in the URI?

Comment: @Shivendra : Yes,  PyMongo supports two step authentication in SCRAM-SHA-1 Mode, as outlined here.

http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html

Comment: in my case the uri should be `mongodb://root:pass@localhost:27017/databse` then get db by `db = client.get_database()`

Answer (score 8):

Just adding more to provided solutions.

I have been using as URI connection string and credentials being provided as f string it helps to reduce number of lines. One thing to note is about special characters in password where we convert using urllib package as shown below.

```
import urllib.parse
from pymongo import MongoClient

host = "localhost"
port = 27017

user_name = "myuser"
pass_word = "Pass@123"  

db_name = "mydb"  # database name to authenticate

# if your password has '@' then you might need to escape hence we are using "urllib.parse.quote_plus()" 
client = MongoClient(f'mongodb://{user_name}:{urllib.parse.quote_plus(pass_word)}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me.

Here you can connect mongodb to python by using authentication username and password.

```
import pymongo

DATABASE_NAME = "your_database_name"
DATABASE_HOST = "localhost"

DATABASE_USERNAME = "database_username"
DATABASE_PASSWORD = "database_password"

try:
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient( DATABASE_HOST )
    myclient.test.authenticate( DATABASE_USERNAME , DATABASE_PASSWORD )
    mydb = myclient[DATABASE_NAME]

    print("[+] Database connected!")
except Exception as e:
    print("[+] Database connection error!")
    raise e
```

By default Mongodb uses `27017` port

Comment: Hi! I was trying this method but in some cases, ie: aws lambda, in some timeout cases, I never notice that.