# python bad authenticate error to mongodb atlas

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-atlas

my code:

```
import certifi
import ssl
from pymongo import MongoClient

connection = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@sensor-cluster-jhiup.mongodb.net/test", ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ssl_ca_certs=certifi.where())
print connection

db = connection.test
print db

items = db.items
print items

db.items.insert_one(
      {"item": "canvas"})
```

I get the following error when trying a simple insert via python 2.7 to mongodb atlas:

> MongoClient(host=['sensor-cluster-shard-00-02-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017',
>   'sensor-cluster-shard-00-00-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017',
>   'sensor-cluster-shard-00-01-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017'],
>   document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True,
>   ssl_ca_certs='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem',
>   replicaset=u'Sensor-Cluster-shard-0', ssl_cert_reqs=2, ssl=True,
>   authsource=u'admin')
>   Database(MongoClient(host=['sensor-cluster-shard-00-02-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017',
>   'sensor-cluster-shard-00-00-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017',
>   'sensor-cluster-shard-00-01-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017'],
>   document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True,
>   ssl_ca_certs='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem',
>   replicaset=u'Sensor-Cluster-shard-0', ssl_cert_reqs=2, ssl=True,
>   authsource=u'admin'), u'test')
>   Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['sensor-cluster-shard-00-02-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017',
>   'sensor-cluster-shard-00-00-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017',
>   'sensor-cluster-shard-00-01-jhiup.mongodb.net:27017'],
>   document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True,
>   ssl_ca_certs='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem',
>   replicaset=u'Sensor-Cluster-shard-0', ssl_cert_reqs=2, ssl=True,
>   authsource=u'admin'), u'test'), u'items')
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/danielmatthews/Python/sunfounderpy3.py", line 18, in 
>       {"item": "canvas"})   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py",
>   line 682, in insert_one
>       session=session),   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py",
>   line 598, in _insert
>       bypass_doc_val, session)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py",
>   line 578, in _insert_one
>       True, _insert_command, session)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py",
>   line 1099, in _retryable_write
>       return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py",
>   line 1066, in _retry_with_session
>       with self._get_socket(server) as sock_info:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py",
>   line 17, in **enter**
>       return self.gen.next()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py",
>   line 944, in _get_socket
>       with server.get_socket(self.**all_credentials) as sock_info:   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py",
>   line 17, in __enter**
>       return self.gen.next()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/server.py",
>   line 138, in get_socket
>       with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py",
>   line 17, in **enter**
>       return self.gen.next()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py",
>   line 893, in get_socket
>       sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py",
>   line 588, in check_auth
>       auth.authenticate(credentials, self)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py",
>   line 486, in authenticate
>       auth_func(credentials, sock_info)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py",
>   line 466, in _authenticate_default
>       return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py",
>   line 237, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
>       res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py",
>   line 496, in command
>       collation=collation)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py",
>   line 125, in command
>       parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py",
>   line 146, in _check_command_response
>       raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response) OperationFailure: bad auth Authentication failed.

Comment: Based on the error message, please double check your credentials (user/password). If the password contains any special chars (i.e. ;#@) please escape them. See also related question: [How To Escape Password in Pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237813/how-to-escape-in-a-password-in-pymongo-connection). If you still have further issues connecting please open a ticket via [MongoDB Atlas Support](https://cloud.mongodb.com/support)