# python with pymongo authenticate faild

Tags: python, mongodb

I set password for mongodb, if password contains “\”,[pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed]. if remove the "\",Authentication success。python version is 2.7 and mongo version is 4.0.I have try any methods still not resovled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3zKU.png)
this is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIcxe.png)
this is the code of connect demo

Comment: Please post the actual error with Traceback message here. Please do not give reference of images.

Comment: Please add description of image

Comment: hava added description

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/39237813/7764309

Comment: it dosen't work, i tried it.

Comment: What version of PyMongo are you using?